# Remote debugging of pure C program with GDB

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, gdb, gdbserver

I am trying to remotely debug a pure `C` program on an Android device.
The Android device (target) is connected via USB to a host machine.

What I did was:
Copied from the **target** the following files:
`/system/lib`, `/vendor/lib`, `/system/bin/app_process`, and `/system/bin/linker`.

**Target:**

- Copied `gdbserver` from `NDK` to the target device
- Sent the `exe` that I want to debug
- runned gdb server on target using `./gdbserver :5039 exec`

  - this basically executes the process, and gets a `pid`

**Host:**

- enabled the port `adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039`
- runned: `arm-eabi-gcc exec`.
- Then in gdb:

  - `set solib-search-path ...`, with the libraries that I pulled earlier from the **target**
  - `target remote :5039`

The `arm-eabi-gcc` can connect to the remote process, and even continue(`c`) the execution. However, I cannot set breakpoints. If I do, I get the following error:
`Cannot access memory at address xxx`.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Debug native Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18143331), [How to Debug native code using ndk-gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17593284), [Gdbserver strange error while debugging native app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26317509), [Debugging Android NDK native apps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8934575), [Debug native code in Android Library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12638849), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at **host**, in gdb shell, before specifying the remote's target port, I should type `shared`. This command loads the shared symbols.

Also, for compiling, I used `-ggdb`.

Comment: I don't believe `-ggdb` has an effect. That's what the GDB folks told me a few years ago on their mailing list. That may have changed.

Comment: emm, so gdb can load the symbols of the debugging program!